# How to add Lombok to a Gradle Java Library project?

Tags: java, gradle, lombok

I tried this:

```
plugins {
  // Apply the java-library plugin to add support for Java Library
  id 'java-library'
  id 'io.freefair.lombok' version '3.8.4'
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Unable to load class 'org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.FindBugsPlugin'.
This is an unexpected error. Please file a bug containing the idea.log file.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Lombok is available in maven central, so telling Gradle to download
> lombok is easy.
>
> **The Lombok Gradle Plugin** There is a plugin for gradle that we recommend you use; it makes deployment a breeze, and makes it easy to
> do additional tasks, such as delomboking. The plugin is open source.
> Read more about the gradle-lombok plugin.
>
> **Gradle without a plugin** If you don't want to use the plugin, gradle has the built-in compileOnly scope, which can be used to tell
> gradle to add lombok only during compilation. Your build.gradle will
> look like:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'
    
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'
}
```

> Remember that you still have to download lombok.jar (or find it in
> gradle's caches) and run it as a jarfile, if you wish to program in
> eclipse. The plugin makes that part easier.

Official site lombok -> https://projectlombok.org/setup/gradle

Comment: I have been using Lombok with `compileOnly` and `annotationProcessor`, the issue here is that the project is a Java Library, and both ways are not working, at least from my side.

Comment: My mistake, since I copied the code from a spring boot `build.gradle`, it was lacking the version. After putting the version it worked. I can not explain why but I am happy with that.